# How can I determine file encodings on Windows / IIS?

Tags: iis, encoding, asp-classic

From the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453647/why-are-accented-characters-rendering-inconsistently-when-accessing-the-same-code) it appears there's a file somewhere on our server that's been saved with the wrong encoding.

I've seen this happen before - most often when pasting from Word into Visual Studio, when "smart quotes" can interfere with Visual Studio's encoding settings when saving the file.

Thing is - the problem I'm having involves 20-30 different script files, include files and so on (hey, that was how we kept it modular back in the day...) and I really don't want to open every one of them in Visual Studio and check the file encodings individually.

Is there any way I can analyze a folder tree full of files and spit out a list of each filename along with the text encoding used to save the file? (Or - if encodings aren't clearly specified - work out what encoding Microsoft IIS *thinks* was used to save the file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textfile's encoding is just how it was intended to be interpreted, so you cannot detect this in a reliable way. You can probably detect UTF-8 and 16-bit unicode, but there's no way distinguishing between ISO-8859-1/2/3/4 etc... (Windows-1250/1251/1252 etc.).

If your document contains "weird" quotes, other than "" or '', you can simply find these, and replace them manually.